# How do i undo the effect of IntersectClipRect?

Tags: windows, delphi, gdi, clipping

Given the following code snippet:

```
procedure TPicture.PaintLine(_Canvas: TCanvas; _Left, _Top, _Right, _Bottom: Integer);
begin
  IntersectClipRect(_Canvas.Handle, _Left, _Top, _Right, _Bottom);
  try
    _Canvas.MoveTo(_Left - 10, _Top - 10);
    _Canvas.LineTo(_Right + 10, _Bottom + 10);
    // (This is an example only, the actual drawing is much more complex.)
  finally
    SelectClipRgn(_Canvas.Handle, 0); // This does too much
  end;
end;
```

I want to undo the clipping effected by the call to IntersectClipRect so the previously active clipping becomes active again. In the above code, this is done by SelectClipRgn(...,0) which turns off clipping altogether. This works, kind of, but afterwards there is no clipping active so any drawing that is executed after the above will paint to areas that should not be painted to.

So, what is the correct way to undo only the effect of IntersectClipRect?

EDIT: Removed the unnecessary CreateRectRgn and DeleteObject code after I understood the comment from Sertac, to make the question more readable for others that might stumble upon it later.

Comment: Unrelated, but just a suggestion... An underscore `_` prefix is typically used for global variables (not related to any object) whereas the prefix `A` is typically suggested for method arguments; or no prefix at all. Nothing hurts if you do it the way you are now, just a suggestion to follow more standard practices. At least you added a prefix to clearly differentiate these, although I suggest use `A` instead of `_` to be more consistent with coding practices.

Comment: I posted an answer considering you're not using in fact the region you created before the 'try' in any way - until the 'finally'. Is your demonstration of the problem correct? or should the code in the question be different?

Comment: @Jerry Dodge: I am not going to discuss coding styles. In my experience this leads to nothing.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: According to the MSDN documentation IntersectClipRect must be passed an existing HRGN.

Comment: @dumm - Read the docs again. As you can see you're not passing any region to it.

Comment: @sertac: Oops, you are right, I confused IntersectClipRect with GetClipRect. Removed it.

Comment: @dumm: Ok, it's not confusing any more. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, first store the current clip region using [`GetClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and after you're done, [`SelectClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the stored region again.

Looking at your code, it should be enough to `SelectClipRgn`your `RGN` again, because:

> The IntersectClipRect function creates a **new** clipping region from the intersection of the current clipping region and the specified rectangle.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to tell me with your second paragraph, but using GetClipRgn and SelectClipRgn did the trick.

Comment: IntersectClipRect will create a new region. The region in your `RGN` should be still unmodified and can be re-selected. Then again I didn't look to closely: You never use that region in your code.

Answer (score 7):

You can [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the state of the DC:

```
var
  //  RGN: HRGN;
  SavedDC: Integer;
begin
//  RGN := CreateRectRgn(_Left, _Top, _Right, _Bottom);
  SavedDC := SaveDC(_Canvas.Handle);
  try
    IntersectClipRect(_Canvas.Handle, _Left, _Top, _Right, _Bottom);
    _Canvas.MoveTo(_Left - 10, _Top - 10);
    _Canvas.LineTo(_Right + 10, _Bottom + 10);
    // (This is an example only, the actual drawing is much more complex.)
  finally
    RestoreDC(_Canvas.Handle, SavedDC);
  end;
  ...
```

Comment: Hm, this might actually be the better solution since in addition to the clipping regions my actual code also saves and restores font, pen, and brush.

Comment: Depending on your code, `SaveDC` might indeed be a better approach.